# Где находиться профиль Mozilla?

Tags: windows, firefox

где мой профиль Mozilla находиться?
у меня есть две папки. какая из них?

\AppData\Local\Mozilla

\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla

Answer (score 1):

Firefox сохраняет папку вашего профиля в этом месте на вашем компьютере, по умолчанию:
`C:\Users\<ваше имя пользователя для входа в Windows>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`

[отсюда](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)